# How do you set a page location when rendering/onload?

Tags: javascript, html

I have a feeling that this is a JavaScript `onload` event. But I'll be damned if I can't figure out how to do this.

```
<body onload="moveToHere('reference')">
```

Help me off the dime.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can accomplish that with the following line:

```
<body onload="location.href='http://www.NewSite.com'">
```

Or if you want to go to a specific location on the current page, just specify the `Id`.

```
<body onload="location.href='#YourLocationId'">
```

Comment: So simple... when you know how.  Thanks all.